# Try and Except inside of a While Loop - Opening files

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, try-catch, except

I am trying to prompt the user for a file to read, and if the file is not found in the directory, it will print a message and then re-prompt the user. For Error Handling I try to use an Try and Except statement and i try to loop it with a while loop. Help please why doesn't this work!

```
while True:

    try:
        input_file = input('Enter the name of the Input File: ' )
        ifile = (input_file, 'r' )
        continue

    except:
        print('File not found. Try again.')
```

Comment: `continue` as the last statement in a loop is redundant. It has no effect.

Comment: You don't open the file anywhere.

Comment: @C.Slates upon receiving a valid file name you need to break out of the look use `break` instead of `continue`

Comment: @melpomene I feel really dumb haha but thanks that helped a ton.

Comment: @shanmuga this also helps me get out of my loop, didn't catch that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense to check with `os.path.isfile`

```
import os

while True:

    input_file = input('Enter the name of the Input File: ')
    if not os.path.isfile(input_file):
        print('File not found. Try again.')
        continue
    break

print('File found!')
```